# skipping the validation procedure of SSL TCP connection

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Ignore certificate errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675133/c-sharp-ignore-certificate-errors)

I am writing code to connect to the remote server through SSL. The code I am currently using is given below. I was getting "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

After some research I found that I have to skip the certificate validation portion of SSL setup . What code should I write to skip the certificate validation?

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("IPADDDRESSHERE", 80);
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(),
            false,
            ValidateServerCertificate,
            null
            );

        try
        {

            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("IPADDDRESSHERE");
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: "*After few research i found that i have to skip the certificate validation portion of SSL setup*": you don't *have* to, you can also do the right thing and choose to trust that particular certificate explicitly.

Comment: can you please tell me what mods should i do in the code?

Comment: What is the definition of ValidateServerCertificate?

Comment: public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
         object sender,
         X509Certificate certificate,
         X509Chain chain,
         SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

            // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
            return true;
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code here:

```
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
        client.GetStream(),
        false,
        ValidateServerCertificate,
        null
        );
```

You are adding a certificate validator, `ValidateServerCertificate`, overriding your previous assignment to `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`.

Try simply using:

```
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
        client.GetStream(),
        false
        );
```