# IdentityServer3 Certificate error - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: ssl-certificate, identityserver3

In Server1 - (IIS hosted, Self Signed Certificate)

- I hosted the IdentityServer3 named myDevIds3.com , the Url is exposed to internet, with SSL.
- I hosted the ASP.Net MVC Client, which uses ids3 for login, works fine.
- I hosted the Web API, which is called by the MVC Client, uses ids3 (in the same server), works fine.

In Development Server / Box.

- I hosted MVC client (X), which uses client side js famework (https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) to connect to Server1 hosted ids3 (myDevIds3.com), works fine.
- I hosted an Web API, which is called by MVC Client (X), while API uses myDevIds3.com for authorisation. [HERE is the problem]

When I try to access this Web API, I am getting an error in the Startup.cs - **The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.**

BUT I tried in other way.

- I hosted another IdentityServer3, the MVC Client, the API also in development box, mapped to local identityserver3 with MVC client & apit, looks everything seems to be working with out any issue. If I put everything together in one box, everything seems to be working.

What is wrong in accessing the remote machine IdentityServer3 in Web API which is hosted in local development Box ? Why I am able to access from the browser, but not from development box IIS ?

Appreciate your time and inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Because your ssl cert is probably home made and not trusted. Guessing Chrome also gives you warning about this (?).

Comment: yes you are right, it was a self signed certificate hosted in server1. So having trusted certificate in the ids3 server (myDevIds3.com), will solve the problem ? So that my Web API in the develop can use the ids3 hosted centralised ? Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks John it clarifies, appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

***CAUTION: This solution is not recommended for production, but this can be used for non production environments, where your data is not critical.***

Add below code in Startup.cs (Web API)

```
ServicePointManager
    .ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

This can be refered in below link aswell.

[C# Ignore certificate errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675133/c-sharp-ignore-certificate-errors)

I found this solution helpful, since I want to have identityserver3 DEV hosted centralised and multiple developers need to access it. Hope it might help someone.