# Install Self-Signed CA Certificate to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, self-signed, ca

I need to install a self-signed CA root certificate that is used by one of our applications that uses Client Certificate Authentication with an external provider.

I have uploaded the .PFX client certificate but I also need to install the CA certificate into the trusted roots.

I have googled endlessly on how to do this and everywhere I look it speaks of Web-Roles, Jobs and Workers, Etc.

We don't have any of these on our project and I am not familiar with how they work or the process of creating / using them. We have a standard ASP.NET MVC 5 web application that we publish to an azure app service, that's about it.

**How do I get this CA certificate installed on Azure?**

I don't mind if I have to use a Web Role / Job / Worker / Whatever but I have never had to configure one before so please advise on how to get setup if that is the correct solution (I.E: If it just requires creating a new project on our VS2015 solution and configuring some deployment settings).

Thanks.
G.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919050655/http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/intermediate-tls-certificates-for-azure-app-service-web-apps/) it's not possible.

> Do note that we will not install new Root certificates in our Trusted Authorities as a result of this, just the intermediate certificates.

That leaves you with two options:

1. Use an Azure Virtual Machine
2. Ignore the fact that the certificate is
   not trusted by Azure

If possible it would be better to handle the certificate policy in-app - then you are in complete control. Assuming you are using .NET then you can either implement an `ICertificatePolicy` with your own validation or just ignore the "error" as per [this SO asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2675183/3818331).

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to run your application on a web or worker role in a cloud service, you can use start-up taks. A start-up task can be either a .bat file or PowerShell script that is executed prior to starting your application. You can also run these scripts elevated if you want.

See also: 
- https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/96926ae6-0cbf-4d00-9dd4-bbe86f93737e/add-certificate-file-to-trusted-root-ca-using-startup-task?forum=windowsazuredevelopment