# async http request is not working (unknown error)

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, httpclient

I simply want to send login data via https and receive the response. The whole thing runs in Visual Studio 2017. When running the program stops when I click the "Login button". I also get no real error but only an unhandled exception.

I'm new to C # maybe i did something wrong with async? Thanks in advance :)

```
 public static async Task<string> GetResponseText(string address)
 {
     using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())          
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(address);
 }

 public void On_Login_Listener(Object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
    string url = "https://localhost/login.php?email=" + email.Text+"&password="+password.Text;

    InfoBox.Text = GetResponseText(url).ToString();
 }
```

Comment: What is the exception type and message?

Comment: the answers below should be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675133/c-sharp-ignore-certificate-errors might also be helpful

Answer (score 2):

The only problem i see is you have not marked your event handler `async`. You need to to mark it `async` and await the `Task` that the method you calling is returning:

```
public async void On_Login_Listener(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string url = "https://localhost/login.php?email=" + email.Text+"&password="+password.Text;

    InfoBox.Text = await GetResponseText(url);
}
```

and a good practice is to postfix the method name with async if it can run asynchrounously :

```
 public static async Task<string> GetResponseTextAsync(string address)
 {
     using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())          
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(address);
 }
```

You need to study more about `async` and `await` to be able to correctly use them. You can read [this great post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for more details and getting better understanding of it.

Answer (score 2):

`GetResponseText` does not return a `string`, it returns a `Task` (it should actually be named `GetResponseTextAsync`). You either need to `await` that task or `Wait` for its `Result`:

Either

```
public void On_Login_Listener(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string url = "https://localhost/login.php?email=" + email.Text+"&password="+password.Text;

    InfoBox.Text = GetResponseText(url).Result;
}
```

or better:

```
// declare as async
public async void On_Login_Listener(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string url = "https://localhost/login.php?email=" + email.Text+"&password="+password.Text;

    InfoBox.Text = await GetResponseText(url);
}
```