# In the VaultSharp library, what's the equivalent of setting the VAULT_CACERT environment variable?

Tags: c#, certificate, vault, vaultsharp

I'm getting the error *An error occurred while sending the request* when using the VaultSharp library in C# to request secrets from a Vault service. I can get the access token I need from the command line, so I know the Vault address and my personal Vault token work.

The CLI relies on the environment variables VAULT_ADDR, VAULT_TOKEN and VAULT_CACERT. I see VaultSharp creates the `VaultClientSettings` object using the first two: address and token information--but where in VaultSharp can I specify the CA certificate path?

Here's the code I'm using, copied from https://github.com/rajanadar/VaultSharp/blob/master/README.md:

```
string vaultToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VAULT_TOKEN");
VaultSharp.V1.AuthMethods.IAuthMethodInfo authMethod = new VaultSharp.V1.AuthMethods.Token.TokenAuthMethodInfo(vaultToken);

string vaultAddress = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VAULT_ADDR");
var vaultClientSettings = new VaultSharp.VaultClientSettings(vaultAddress, authMethod);
VaultSharp.VaultClient vaultClient = new VaultSharp.VaultClient(vaultClientSettings);

string vaultRoute = Properties.Settings.Default.VaultRoute;
VaultSharp.V1.Commons.Secret<VaultSharp.V1.Commons.SecretData> kv2Secret = await vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync(vaultRoute);
```

It's this last statement `ReadSecretAsync` that throws the error.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Kevin, is your Vault's SSL Cert trusted by your calling app? If not, you maybe getting SSL errors. You may have to ignore it. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675133/c-sharp-ignore-certificate-errors

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of VAULT_CACERT in VaultSharp. VaultSharp expects your Vault URL to have a trusted SSL Cert. If not, you will get TLS errors while establishing the handshake. And in non-prod environments, folks typically use the following snippet to solve for it.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
  (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; // or do specific checks
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried this & now get a "permission denied" error that sounds like it's related to permissions on our Vault server. I'll check with the team that set that up. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Let me know if any further VaultSharp issues.