# Suppress SSL Certificate through .Net Framework

Tags: ssl-certificate, .net-framework-version, suppress-warnings

if https shows any warning related to SSL certificate how to suppress this kind of warnings through .Net API call or any other ways to restrict through coding in .Net framework.

[image]

Referred these documents

- [ignore Certificate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675133/c-sharp-ignore-certificate-errors)
- [Bypass SSL certificate validation](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2014/september/bypass-ssl-certificate-validation/)

Comment: Don't. Certificate errors show potential security problems and must **NEVER** be ignored. Just fix the root cause instead. BTW, the dialog seems like an Internet Explorer certificate error, not your own program.

Comment: If you have this as your current problem, then the real problem is you need a new SSL cert .. if you need to bypass it because despite being out of date, it is "correct" and perhaps its an internal network, you could allow the user to click YES and Proceed anyways... the only way to get around this it to turn off the SSL requirement in IIS and that is NOT suggested on an environment that was previously encrypted.  Granted if the API is only external information it MIGHT be okay .. but if the user is providing KEYS or Login information or anything secure, you NEED that SSL in place.